# How can I delay twitter requests

Tags: webservices, social-media

Using the twitter ServiceConnection it is easy to build the friend network of a twitter account:

```
twitter = ServiceConnect["Twitter", "New"]
twitter["FollowerNetwork", "Username" -> "elonmusk"]
```

However, the requests are made too frequently and after some minutes I get blocked by the twitter API resulting in an incomplete graph.

How can I delay the requests to be limited to what twitter allows per minute?

For example, the tweepy python library has a setting **wait_on_rate_limit** https://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.2.0/api.html#API

Comment: If Python already has the functionality you are looking for, how about using [ExternalEvaluate](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ExternalEvaluate.html) to import the Tweepy module into Mathematica?

Comment: Reading the docs page, it does seem like the service connection knows about the rate limit (as you can ask for `"RateLimit"`) but, especially for `"FollowerNetwork"` you are relying on underlying code that isn't doing anything about the rate limit. You could roll your own version of it that waits a certain amount of time between requests, or use `ExternalEvaluate` suggested by @user10181864. Or you could simply run the code on someone with fewer than 49 million followers :)

Comment: @CarlLange thanks. I guess I switch to python for this task then. I just wonder why there is such a function when it is basically useless in practice. Elon Musk was just an example, I cannot scrape accounts with even 160 followers easily. I wouldn't mind taking this long, so a delay would be ok.

Comment: You could also file a bug with WRI. It's possible that the twitter API's rate limiting has changed since the function was originally written, making this function unviable in its current form (I think 160 followers should work just fine)